# How do I make a video preview of my Android game?

Tags: android

I noticed some apps have a link to a Youtube video instead of a screenshot in Google's Android Play store.  How can I make a video of my Android game running on a physical device?  The emulator won't work for me (my game uses the camera preview feed). I guess I could take a video of the phone with another device, but that seems a little cheesy to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are programs available to capture video on the physical device. See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/how-to-capture-video-of-my-mobile-game) about that. Beyond that, I think you have an opportunity here to not just make a video capture of your game, but to make a trailer. Check out [this article](http://blog.kertgartner.com/2012/03/making-entertaining-and-engaging-video-game-trailers/) on making video game trailers to see what time/resources you have to making a excellent trailer.

Comment: Thanks to the link to the question about the "DroidScreen" program.  This isn't the ideal for my game because of the noticeable time lag between frames captured.  Since I'm using the camera preview, I was hoping to find something that produces a "smoother" video (so folks don't thing it will play "choppy" on their device).  Also, thanks for the link on the trailer article...that's a great idea!

Comment: That'll be tricky. If you're not capturing smooth video now, it's possible your hardware is not powerful enough. Video screen capture is resource intensive. I can only suggest borrowing someone's device that's more powerful or making a "sample" of your application using pre-recorded video from your device with your game overlay on top. Or faking it essentially. Sorry I wasn't able to help more. Good luck!

Comment: A good answer to the lag, is making the video on your own game. How? If you have fixed framerate, take one screenshot per frame them join them at the right speed (1 / framerate). If not, take a ss with the current delta time as the shot stamp. then join them with this time. This should be pretty neat, and maybe hard to implement, but will grant you that even if the recording is slow, the result will be smooth.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel That would work if using pre-recorded video so you could play it back at the same framerate.

Comment: @byte56 Yes, that was my idea. Some games use this technique to make their replays. Something like saving the game state every frame and then replaying at the same rate. But here it could be something like just images. Then you can work them out into a movie.

Comment: @GustavoMaciel You should add that as an additional answer. Since it's pretty separate from my original answer and it's useful. We can remove these comments once that's done, as to not double up information.

Answer (score 1):

Some phones(or tablets) have an HDMI output, you can connect your HDMI cable to a video recorder linked to your PC.